# Binning into 10 bins for each column

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am trying to create binning of 10 bins for each column in the dataframe. The input will be a csv file and output should be in JSON for each column binned into 10.

**Given a input file, the output should display binned values for each column with the help of percentiles (1, 5, 10, 25, 50, 75, 90, 95, 99)**

This is the code which i have till now.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('train.csv')


def func(column):
    return pd.cut(column, bins=10)


a = df.apply(func, axis=1)

print(a)
```

Please shed some light on this. Thanks

Comment: So what is your question here?

Comment: Do you have an id or primary key which can be used to creat bins?

Comment: I have percentiles  (1, 5, 10, 25, 50, 75, 90, 95, 99)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, Not sure if I totally understand your question, but maybe you want `axis=0` instead of `axis=1` (`axis=1` is rows).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the question is an old one and not clear, but Binning is an important subject for some people learning python so I preferred to add this feedback here:

I found a good example of binning on this article:
See [#10 – Cut function for binning](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/01/12-pandas-techniques-python-data-manipulation/)